# IllegalStateException in one of the handlers

Tags: android, handler, illegalstateexception

I am having following exception, I can't understand the reason for this. I tried googling, but failed to find a proper solution. Can someone please let me know what is causing this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.os.MessageQueue.removeSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:266)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.os.Looper.removeSyncBarrier(Looper.java:242)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1222)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5089)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-09 15:28:53.967: W/System.err(20676):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it is a good idea if you post some code!

Comment: Refer [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868635/thread-handler-error-the-specified-message-queue-synchronization-barrier-token) and lemme know if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not paste code because it is huge code working on handler. It was written by some people over the years.

Thanks Sash_KP your link solved the issue. I had seen it, earlier but was not sure which handler was causing the issue.

This issue is solved by changing calls to the Handler's sendMessage method, to dispatchMessage.